# How to clear object store in Mule 3

Tags: mule, mulesoft

In my application I use timestamp to query data. The query use the time of now and that last succes run time. I do this to make sure there is no data will be lost in between. This approach also has drawbacks, of course, which is that if the application has any issue for a long time or will crash, a lot of data has to be retrieved at once. Because the application uses the timestamp of the last success run, of course.

Internally, the application runs like the following. A query is executed based on the timestamp and the received payload is used in a foreach loop. Now during testing I run into the issue that the retrieved data is always the same. Even though I change the value from object store to hard value. I keep getting the same payload. It seems that the value used is from the cache. I tried with the operation "Dispose store" and “Remove” but that doesn't work either. Does anyone know how I can delete the object store cache locally but also on the Privet cloud edition?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please provide the configuration of the object store and examples of the operations you are using to store and delete the object store. Provide text XML in your question, not screenshots.

Comment: @aled, I have added in my new question all the XML code.